# SAGA grid tools missing in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, saga

Grid options are missing in SAGA toolbox. If I go to options in processing the following message is being displayed. How should I change the path?[image: screenshot of my problem]

Comment: You may have some remains of old QGIS installation on your computer and therefore the wrong path is found. Try to uninstall all the versions which you have and delete the QGIS settings folder from \user\.qgis2 and then re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the grid option issue, the error message you received may have come from GRASS setting, not from SAGA.

One of following setting on Processing Options may work for you;

1. Deactivate **GRASS commands** and activate **GRASS GIS 7 Commands** instead. GRASS7 does not require MSYS.
2. Under **GRASS commands** add MSYS folder if it is blank. You can create any new empty folder and name it msys and assign.

Make sure GRASS folder (or GRASS7 folder) is set properly. Sometimes (especially after minor QGIS updates) Processing Options fails to pick up correct folder path.

[image]