# SAGA grid tools not found on QGis 2.14.15

Tags: qgis, saga

I am missing all grid tools from SAGA in QGis 2.14.15.

I know it's a question that has been asked before (there : [SAGA grid tools missing in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222921/saga-grid-tools-missing-in-qgis) ) but unfortuately the answer given in this post did not fix my issue. I did have the GRASS folders not correctly configurated and fixed it, but it didn't have any influence on the SAGA tools (and I fail to see why it would have had any influence on it anyway since those are different plugins...).
I also tried to un-install and re-install QGis, but the tools still did not appear. I tried some other SAGA tools and they work perfectly. And QGis is in english so it's not an issue with the name of the algorithms either.

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

EDIT : 
I am on Windows 10 and I have SAGA 2.3.2, which seems to be working fine on its own, but I'm not too familiar with the software on its own, I've always used it trhough QGis only... I can see the grid tools in SAGA's own interface by the way, they just don't appear in the QGis processing tool menu.

Comment: What OS are you on? Which SAGA version have you installed? Does SAGA run ok as standalone?

Comment: I am on Windows 10 and I have SAGA 2.3.2, which seems to be working fine on its own, but I'm not too familiar with the software on its own, I've always used it trhough QGis only... I can see the grid tools in SAGA's own interface by the way, they just don't appear in the QGis processing tool menu.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

The SAGA `Grid Tools` seem to be implemented in the Processing tools as `Raster Tools`.

Note that Processing does not automatically support **ALL** SAGA modules you have installed. For every SAGA module there needs to be an interface in Processing. If noone has created it (yet), you will not find this module in Processing.

Apart from that, you may have some remains of old QGIS installation (especially the old processing plugin which was not a core module at the time) on your computer and therefore the wrong path is found. Try to delete the QGIS settings folder `C:\users\<username>\.qgis2` and restart.

Comment: Thanks for both of your answer! I get that all SAGA modules may not have been implemented in the processing tool, but I had the feeling that the specific tool that I was looking for (shapes to grid) was quite commonly used, so I believe it should be there. It is not under the raster tools either, unfortunately. Still thanks for the insightful advices and remarks :)

Comment: @Owlxymore The `shapes to grid` you are looking for is called `Rasterize` and can be found in `QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Raster creation tools | Rasterize`.

Comment: @Kazuhito  You're absolutely right, thanks!!! Any idea if others SAGA grid tools are also available but under another name in QGis processing toolbox?

Comment: @Owlxymore You can find a list here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaNameDecorator.py#L95. See this issue: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17041#change-81730